# Unity How to turn off a gameObject's Mesh Collider when a collison on another object is done?

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, unityscript

On my unity project I have encountered a problem I want to collide with an object then I want to turn on the mesh collider of an other gameObject this is my code now...

```
#pragma strict

private var objManager : ObjectiveManager;
private var ob2 : MeshCollider;

function Start()
{
    objManager = GameObject.Find("3rdPersonController").GetComponent(ObjectiveManager);
    ob2 = GameObject.Find("Objective2").GetComponent(MeshCollider);

}

function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "3rdPersonController")

            ob2.enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("whooop");
            Destroy(gameObject);
            objManager.objective1 = true;
            objManager.objective2 = false;
            objManager.objective3 = false;
            objManager.objective4 = false;
            objManager.objective5 = false;
            objManager.objective6 = false;
            objManager.objective7 = false;
            objManager.objective8 = false;
            objManager.objective9 = false;
            objManager.objective10 = false;
            objManager.objective11 = false;
            objManager.objective12 = false;



}
```

Comment: OMG thanks that was it much bro <3

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. Were the curly brackets the solution to the problem?

Comment: Yeah the if statement wasn't even doing anything it was just there lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer so it can be closed.

The problem here is that your If-statement has no curly braces, causing the code after it to run regardless of how the boolean evaluates.